# const_cast seems to be ignored with C++ templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants, const-cast

I wrote a simple logging class that supports variadic templates in C++ using Visual Studio on Windows. I created a generic `Log` function template with a number of specializations to cater for a common combination of possible inputs.

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

inline static string to_utf8(const wstring& s) {
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> utf16conv;
    return utf16conv.to_bytes(s);
}

class Logger {
public:
    HANDLE file_handle;
    wchar_t file_path[MAX_PATH + 1];

    inline Logger(HANDLE handle) : file_handle(handle), file_path{} {
    }

    inline Logger(const string& path) : Logger(path.c_str()) {
    }

    inline Logger(const wstring& path) : Logger(path.c_str()) {
    }

    inline Logger(const char* path) : file_handle(NULL) {
        wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
        wcscpy_s(file_path, MAX_PATH + 1, converter.from_bytes(path).c_str());
    }

    inline Logger(const wchar_t* path) : file_handle(NULL) {
        wcscpy_s(file_path, MAX_PATH + 1, path);
    }

private:
    inline void VerifyInitialize() {
        if ((file_handle == NULL || file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && file_path[0] != '\0') {
            file_handle = CreateFileW(file_path, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            SetFilePointer(file_path, 0, NULL, FILE_END);
        }
    }

public:
    inline void Log() {
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const char* first, Rest... params) {
        VerifyInitialize();
        if (file_handle == NULL || file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return;
        DWORD written;
        WriteFile(file_handle, first, static_cast<DWORD>(strlen(first)), &written, NULL);
        Log(params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const char first, Rest... params) {
        char str[2];
        str[0] = first;
        str[1] = '\0';
        Log(str, params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const string* first, Rest... params) {
        VerifyInitialize();
        if (file_handle == NULL || file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return;
        DWORD written;
        WriteFile(file_handle, first->c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(first->size()), &written, NULL);
        Log(params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const string& first, Rest... params) {
        Log(&first, params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const wstring* first, Rest... params) {
        Log(*first, params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const wstring& first, Rest... params) {
        Log(to_utf8(first), params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const wchar_t* first, Rest... params) {
        Log(wstring(first), params...);
    }

    template<typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(const wchar_t first, Rest... params) {
        wchar_t str[2];
        str[0] = first;
        str[1] = '\0';
        Log(str, params...);
    }

    template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
    inline void Log(First first, Rest... params) {
        printf("%s\n", typeid(First).name());
        if (is_const<First>::value) {
            stringstream stream;
            stream << first;
            Log(stream.str(), params...);
        } else
            Log(const_cast<const First>(first), params...);
    }

    inline ~Logger() {
        if (!(file_handle == NULL || file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) {
            CloseHandle(file_handle);
            file_handle = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

The code works fine with const values. If however I introduce non-const parameters like so:

```
int main() {
    Logger logger(("output.txt"));
    wchar_t sometext[3];
    sometext[0] = '1';
    sometext[1] = '8';
    sometext[2] = '\0';
    logger.Log(sometext, L"\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the specializations are not called and instead the last generic `void Log(First first, Rest... params)` is called, which uses `stringstream` and writes the pointer as a string instead of the string itself.

If I remove `const` from all overload parameters, when I invoke `main()` it works, but if I replace `sometext` with a `const char*`, then the last generic `void Log(First first, Rest... params)` is called instead of the specializations (ie. removing `const` does not solve the problem).

So, in order to try the get the best of both worlds, I tried adding the following condition:

```
template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
inline void Log(First first, Rest... params) {
    if (is_const<First>::value) {
        stringstream stream;
        stream << first;
        Log(stream.str(), params...);
    } else
         Log(const_cast<const First>(first), params...);
}
```

with the rationale being to instruct the compiler to *"first search for a const specialization overload, and if none was found, then fallback to using `stringstream`"*.

However, I was getting a stack overflow. To debug, I added `printf("%s\n", typeid(First).name());` just before the `if` condition, and the output was:

```
wchar_t * __ptr64
wchar_t * __ptr64
wchar_t * __ptr64
wchar_t * __ptr64
....
```

Apparently, `const_cast<const First>(first)` does not seem to be in fact casting to `const`, even though `is_const::value` is indeed returning `false`. I have also tried using `std::as_const`, but there was no difference in the outcome.

Why is the cast not working? How do I resolve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `First` is `wchar_t*` the cast will create a `wchar_t* const`, not a `const wchar_t*`. The cast is not a text substitution of the type names.

So you create a new type that doesn't match any specialization, and get a recursive call to the generic `Log` function.

Comment: Apart from the "const to pointer" specialization, I added a "pointer to const" specialization for every type, and everything worked! A million thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

[const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) is only used for casting a type from const to non-const. And this only works if the said variable was not originally declared as const.

You don't need to *cast* something to const, you can just copy it to a const reference or const value of that type

```
const char* changeSecond(char* string, char change)
{
  string[0] = change;
  return string;
}
```

That function will return a `const char*`, without casting needed. This can also be done with assignment.